# ANTLR4 parser detection

Tags: parsing, antlr4

This is my first try with an ANTLR4-grammar. It should recognize a very easy statement, starting with the command 'label', followed by a colon, then an arbitrary text, ended by semicolon. But the parser does not recognize 'label' as description. Why?

```
grammar test;



 prog: stat+;

  stat:  
    description content
  ;

  description: 
     'label' COLON   
  ;

  content: 
    TEXT 
  ;

  TEXT: 
     .*? ';'
  ;

  STRING : '"' ('""'|~'"')* '"' ; // quote-quote is an escaped quote

  COMMENT
    : '//' (~('\n'|'\r'))*
  ; 

  COLON      : ':' ;
  ID: [a-zA-z]+;
  INT: [0-9]+;
  NEWLINE: '\r'? '\n';
  WS  :   [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

An example for the code:

```
label: 
this is an error;


wronglabel:YYY
this should be a error;
```

The error is:

line 1:0 mismatched input 'label: \nthis is an error;' expecting 'label'
(prog label: \nthis is an error; \n\n\nwronglabel:YYY\nthis should be a error; \n)

Comment: Aside: Isn't this wrong: `ID: [a-zA-z]+;`?

Comment: It seems to be correct. I compared it to ID-definitions in other examples, it seems to be the common way to define an ID consisting solely of letters.

Comment: If I modify the TEXT-token in this way:

    TEXT: 
      '"' .*? '"' ';'
     ;

it works much better.
Still I don't know exacty, why.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. What I meant was, shouldn't the second z be upper case?

Comment: Now I see: of cause you're right!

Comment: could the problem have to do with the order of processing?
Maybe TEXT is defined too general?

Answer (score 1):

This works much better:

```
grammar test;

 prog: stat+;

  stat:  
    description content
  ;

  description: 
     'label' COLON   
  ;

  content: 
    text 
  ;

  text: 
     .*? ';'
  ;

  STRING : '"' ('""'|~'"')* '"' ; // quote-quote is an escaped quote

  COMMENT
    : '//' (~('\n'|'\r'))*
  ; 

  COLON      : ':' ;
  ID: [a-zA-z]+;
  NEWLINE: '\r'? '\n';
  WS  :   [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

Seems I mixed lexer and parser rules:
lexer rules have to be lower case,
parser rules uppercase.
So I changed the TEXT-rule into a text-rule.